# Print problems in GVIM

Tags: printing, vim

I have set linebreak and wrap.
The document looks great on my screen but when I print it the words are broken p.e.

```
this is the text of my printed docume
nt
```

How can I resolve this problem?

ps: I don't want to reformat the text, I would like to keep the text as it is on the screen.

I would like to have also a bit more right margin space.
Is this possible?

Comment: Not a direct answer, and not sure if you're printing code... but if you are, check out 'enscript'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't directly possible. When you use `wrap`, Vim breaks lines at word boundaries on the *screen*, but the actual text file still contains your lines as single unbroken strings. If you want to fix this you have to reformat your file (possibly copying it to a temp file) before you print. See this similar question: [How do you enable word wrap in vim when printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533385/how-do-you-enable-word-wrap-in-vim-when-printing)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to look exactly like it would on your screen, then you'll likely want to use something like the [2html](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#2html.vim) script to dump it to html and then print that.  Otherwise, Vim just sends the file to the printer and the file is formatted according to whatever [print options](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'printoptions') you have set.